# SSRS - Hiding a Parameter In a Tabbed Report When Moving Between Pages

Tags: reporting-services

I created a tabbed report (Manually) using two different data sets. For each data set I created a tablix, and I used a page breaker between them. I created different parameters for both tables, and I was wondering if there's any way to hide the other table's parameters when moving between the pages?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortuantely, no, paramaters cannot be hidden conditionally!